# How to launch a program in text only mode if it support silent running

Tags: aix, tty

I have got a java program, which support text file input and auto running, can i put it in background running without GUI ?

It prompt cannot set display.

while there is no concern to view the display, it can just run the file input and finish the job.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a virtual X server like `Xvfb` for this. That is (not only) for X what `/dev/null` is for the console. You run `Xvfb` and set DISPLAY to it.

I don't have practical experience with this so I cannot give you details. But that should be the way to go.

Comment: nice idea, but can it be do without installation? The server was request by some auditor to disabled X windows completely, i am not sure if this can be allowed.

Comment: @AntonyLee We are in the pre-Wayland era so it is easily possible to redirect this to an IP address (of another server). There will be hardly any traffic (depending on the software, of course). The arguments against X on a server do not apply here. You need not have X installed for this. If it was forbidden to use a virtual X server then one might ask what sense it made to allow the execution of X clients.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run the program in a tty just to make sure it will not crash on you if there is no "display".

If that works then probably this will work aswell:

```
$(unset DISPLAY; java your_stuff_here)
```

what this does is spawn a subshell (hence the $(...) ) and clears the DISPLAY variable.

I remember this working for some GUI apps which I wanted to run without a GUI